# Date format in the spring boot repository testing

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing, simpledateformat, assertj

I am using the following codes to do the integration testing for repository functions. However, it will fail because of the date formart. The output from SimpleDateFormat is 'Wed Jan 01 10:10:10 MST 2020', but the date from database is '2020-01-01 10:10:10.0'. Is their any easy way to handle this issue?

```
      Optional<TestBean> testBean = testBeanRepository.findById(1L);
      TestBean toReturn = new TestBean();
      toReturn.setAccountNumber(123456789);
      toReturn.setId(1L);
      toReturn.setCustomerName("Peter");
      toReturn.setModifiedDate(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss").parse("2020-01-01 10:10:10"));
      assertThat(testBean)
         .isPresent()
         .hasValue(toReturn);
```

This is how I defined modified date(java.util.date):

```
@Column(name = "MODIFIED_DATE_TIME") 
@NotNull 
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) 
private Date modifiedDate;
```

Comment: Change your format to match the database, perhaps? Can you elaborate on how you attempted to solve the problem, it's not clear from your code where your attempt is.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use for example `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Detail, I’d prefer `assertThat(testBean).isEqualTo(Optional.of(toReturn))`. Seems simpler to me, and will give you a very nice error message no matter if the result contains a wrong value, is empty or even null.

Comment: What type is `setModifiedDate()` declared to accept? `java.util.Date`? Can you change it to modern type? `Instant` is probably appropriate, depending on exact requirements.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes. I am using ```java.util.Date```. And ```@Column(name = "MODIFIED_DATE_TIME")
   @NotNull
   @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
   private Date modifiedDate;```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem to me that `TestBean` is declared to hold a `java.util.Date`, but the `TestBean` instance returned from `findById()` instead holds a `java.sql.Timestamp`. It’s very unfortunate (if it’s true).

`Timestamp` is implemented as a subclass of `Date`. Both classes are poorly designed and long outdated, we should not use them anymore. In spite of the subclass relationship, accordindg to the documentation we should not regard `Timestamp` as a kind of `Date`. Implementing `Timestamp` as a subclass of `Date` is a true hack. And putting a `Timestamp` into a `Date` field in your object is wrong. I also don’t think it was ever the intention that we should use `Timestamp` in our model beans. It was for transferring data to and from SQL database columns with datatype `timestamp` and `timestamp with time zone` only.

So the good solution is: Change your `TestBean` class to hold a modern date-time object belonging to a class of java.time, the modern Java date and time API. *Edit:* Since your datatype in MySQL is `datetime`, the best match in Java is `LocalDateTime`. A `LocalDateTime` is a date and time of day without time zone or UTC offset.

If you cannot change the type declared in the `TestBean` class, there are still a couple of possible improvements:

- Make sure the object holds a `Date` object as it’s declared to do, not a `Timestamp`.
- Add a getter and setter that return and accept an `Instant` rather than a `Date` so that your class can better interoperate with code using java.time. The new methods would do the necessary conversion. Then use the new setter for setting the value in `toReturn`.

If you can’t do any of this either and you’re forced to being part of the hack, there are of course ways to set `modifiedDate` to an old-fashioned `Timestamp`. I suggest:

```
    toReturn.setModifiedDate(Timestamp.from(Instant.parse("2020-01-01T17:10:10Z")));
```

I have given the time as 17:10:10. This time is in UTC (denoted by the `Z`). I assumed that the MST mentioned in your question is North American Mountain Standard Time (not Malaysian Standard Time?), and if so, this time corresponds to the desired 10:10:10 in your time zone.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Documentation of `java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using java.util.date, and I am using temporal in the field declaration. How should I change it? I have updated my question.

Comment: It depends on your JPA implementation and version, your database engine and the datatype of the `MODIFIED_DATE_TIME` column in the database. Maybe you can simply declare the field for example `OffsetDateTime` or `Instant` (whether you still need the `@Temporal` annotation then, I don’t know).

Comment: I am using MySQL, and datatype of the date is DATETIME.

Comment: Then try `LocalDateTime` in Java, it’s the best match for MySQL `datetime`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is Parsing(String to Date), you need to Format(Date to String).

```
SimpleDateFormat readFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat writeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss");

Optional<TestBean> testBean = testBeanRepository.findById(1L);
TestBean toReturn = new TestBean();
toReturn.setAccountNumber(123456789);
toReturn.setId(1L);
toReturn.setCustomerName("Peter");
toReturn.setModifiedDate(writeFormat.format(readFormat.parse("2020-01-01 10:10:10")));
assertThat(testBean)
        .isPresent()
        .hasValue(toReturn);
```

Here `readFormat` and `writeFormat` are same but they can be different.

Comment: modifiedDate is type of java.util.Date. I have updated my question.